# Where can I find Gaming Experience Questionnaire (GEQ) ?

Tags: experimental-psychology, video-games

I am currently doing a research about computer games and in my experiment set up I need to asses each players gaming experience via **Gaming Experience Questionnaire (GEQ)**. Is there any place I can obtain a sample GEQ and the scoring criteria ?

Comment: Where have you seen this questionnaire before? Is there a paper that references it or uses it?